# Passing an array of objects to Member Function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, turbo-c++

I use Turbo C++ and am experiencing an unexpected error in my code, please help..
I am trying to pass an array of objects to a member function.
An error : Undefined structure test , pops on the line where i define my print function

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class test
{
     int t;
public:
     void print(test T[])
     {
          cout<<"This Test\n";
     }
};
void main()
{
     clrscr();
     test T1,T2[5];
     T1.print(T2);
     getch();
}
```

I have to use the outdated version of the Turbo C++ compiler at school so the syntax of the code might be different than the new compilers.

Comment: I'm really puzzled by fact there are still teachers/schools using that outdated thing (I struggle to call it a _version_) of a C++ compiler.

Comment: I'm sure only someone using turbo whatever will be able to reproduce the error. So find one such person and ask them.

Comment: After doing some modification to run with GCC, [couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1Fxw6jFzMnjE2dKW).

Comment: thats sad...i thought someone here would know this

Comment: also schools all over india teach c++ using this piece of shit compiler

Comment: I actually found an online version of Turbo C++... https://www.naclbox.com/gallery/turboc

Comment: pass array as pointer: `void print(test* T, int num)`

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: Have you tried to forward declare your class?

Comment: @nikitoz The parameter is already a pointer (at least in standard C and C++.)

Comment: @Bob__ How would that help?  The function is inside the class so the name `test` is already known.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, normal compiler will silently turn argument to a pointer, but here we have turboc. [link](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/9/3/428)

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, that compiler had to be broken somehow, I made an educated guess based on the error text: _"Undefined structure test"_

Comment: @Bob__ Ah I see.  You were guessing it was not introducing the name.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from compiling your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your function as `void print(test *T)`.

Turbo C++ is broken in the regard of parameters of type `test[]` being equivalent to `test*`.

Comment: one more thing, why did it work as a pointer but not as an array?

Comment: @Shashank the two signatures are identical from a language stand point. TC++ is just bad